# Angular not defined even though included it in tag

Tags: angular

I have problem with Angular that it always said the variable angular was not defined even though I have included it in the html tags[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KODmM.png)
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Xlx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `<script>` tag where you load AngularJs:

`<srcipt></srcipt>` ---> `<script></script>`